# Button overflow hidden not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

[image]

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gxe3d59u/)

html:

```
<button>Here's a long chunk of text</button>
```

css:

```
button {
   width: 80px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Basically, I want the button not to wrap the text..

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: you could also specify a `height`, if for some reason the `white-space:nowrap` solution isn't suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following style to prevent line breaks:

```
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gxe3d59u/3/)

**EDIT**

Now, since you're trying to hide the overflow, I'd suggest to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to give better looks to the text cut, adding a (...) at the end:

[**Another Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gxe3d59u/4/)

```css
button {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<button>Here's a long chunk of text</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;`:

```css
button {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<button>Here's a long chunk of text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `white-space:nowrap;`

```
button {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxe3d59u/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

add `white-space: nowrap;` and `word-wrap: normal;`

`word-wrap:` The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

`white-space:` The white-space property specifies how white-space inside an element is handled.

```css
button {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<button>Here's a long chunk of text</button>
```